# TeeChart: Adding candles to chart without specifying their time

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm looking for a way to add data to OHLC series without specifying date values of the point.

So let's assume that I have a `List<Candle>` where `Candle` object contain values for `high`, `low`, `open` and `close`, but *not* the `date`.

I'd like to add values to series in such a way that they will be regularly distributed on the chart, I mean, there will be equal distance between all candles.

Is there any convenient options to add point to the end and to the beginning of the series' data list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an override of the add() method accepting `open`, `high`, `low` and `close` values:

```
public int add(double open, double high, double low, double close)
```

And another accepting `index`, `open`, `high`, `low` and `close` values:

```
public int add(int index, double open, double high, double low, double close)
```

---

UPDATE:

In the project you sent, I see you are removing the first point of the series after a few iterations:

```
candleSeries.delete(0);
```

Note the first add() override mentioned above internally calls the second:

```
public int add(double open, double high, double low, double close) {
    return add(getCount(), open, high, low, close);
}
```

So, the Count of the series is being used as XValue for the point being added. But removing the first point you are loosing the sync of Count and XValues, and this makes the first override of the add() method not to be the appropriate in this situation.

In your case, you could still use a third override of the add() method, accepting `index`, `open`, `high`, `low` and `close` values:

```
public int add(double index, double open, double high, double low, double close)
```

Note the first parameter of is override is named "index" but it's actually a double so you can consider it a XValue/Date.

This is, in your test application, change this:

```
candleSeries.add(point.getOpen(), point.getHigh(), point.getLow(), point.getClose());
```

For this:

```
candleSeries.add(candleSeries.getXValues().getValue(candleSeries.getCount()-1) + 1, point.getOpen(), point.getHigh(), point.getLow(), point.getClose());
```

Comment: will the first overload add the value as the last value in the list?

Comment: I've tried to adding bars using `public int add(double open, double high, double low, double close)` overload.
There's also code in my app that removes the first (from the left) bar using `series.delete(0)` and the last bar using `series.delete(series.getCount() - 1)` methods. And sometimes I get issues when one bar is shown on top of the other one, or even series is duplicated on the chart... Should I somehow refresh the chart after manipulating series' data?

Comment: @Dennis You shouldn't need to refresh the chart after adding or deleting points with those methods. It would be helpful if you could arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problems here. You can send it to "info at steema dot com", or if you prefer you can edit your question here and add a comment.

Comment: I sent an example project to your e-mail just a minute ago. I've reproduced the issue with SWT version of the library.

Comment: I've just answered your mail and edited my answer above